# how to call http post in custom scenario like this in angular?

Tags: angular, http-post

I have created custom post method with almost same signature with original one like this ,

```
postcall(url: string, body: any | null, options: {headers?: HttpHeaders | {
          [header: string]: string | string[];
      };
       params?: HttpParams | {
          [param: string]: string | string[];
      };
      reportProgress?: boolean;
      responseType?: 'arraybuffer' | 'blob' | 'json' | 'text';
      withCredentials?: boolean;
  } = {}): Observable<any> {

    return this.http.post<any>(url,body,options.Headers?Headers:responseType);


  }
```

I am unable to pass option as parameter with above post call.Please let me how I can pass the argument. it should pass the options as we receive in postcall()'s formal argument.

edit-1,

My call would be

```
this.http.postcall(this.resumeapiserver,body,{responseType: 'text'});
```

or

```
 httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      
    })
  }

this.http.postcall(this.apiServer + '/applicants/', JSON.stringify(applicant), this.httpOptions)
```

this both should work ..

[image: I am unable to make this call with following error,]

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ke493.png]

[image: error I am getting if I pass option directly]

Comment: Show us more code.. Please show us the options that you would like to send via post

Comment: @manzapanza  my call will something like this,  this.http.postcall(this.apiServer + '/applicants/', JSON.stringify(test), this.httpOptions)   or   this.http.postcall(this.apiserver,body,{responseType: 'text'});         this both call  should work

Comment: To help us to help you, you should edit your question.. with all relevant code.. I suggest to you to remove the code that you put there, and place the real code that doesn't works

Comment: @manzapanza edited please check one more time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like that:

```
  post(applicant: any) {
    const options = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }),
    };
    this.http.post(this.apiServer + '/applicants/', applicant, options);
  }
```

Your `postcall` function has an error, probably should be changed this line as follow:

```
    return this.http.post<any>(url, body, options);
```

In my opinion, is not make al lot of sense this `postcall` function because is a copy of the httpClient post function. So, maybe, is better use directly the post function as I showed to you in my first example code.

Comment: actually I want to make my own http service class which will handle all post call.this also not working this.http.post<any>(url, body, options.responseType); I want to use any option not only options.responseType

Comment: getting an error "No overload matches this call."given screenshot at the last of my question.

Comment: Your declaration type of the options parameter is wrong..